# Rails Amazon s3, Paperclip missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use Paperclip and Amazon S3 in a rails application. And the weird part is that it worked before I stored my variables in the environment.yml

I get the error

> ArgumentError - missing required :bucket option:

Here is my environment development:

```
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:  "myid"
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: secretkey
  AWS_BUCKET: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-1-299430007588.s3.amazonaws.com8
```

in the config/environments/development.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
   :storage => :s3
   :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
   }
  }
```

then in the production

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
   :storage => :s3
   :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
   }
  }
```

In my Recipe model

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
      validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
      has_attached_file :download,
                        :storage => :s3,
                        :s3_credentials => Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials }



      def s3_credentials
         {:bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'], :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']}
      end
```

The gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
gem 'aws-sdk','< 2.0'
```

Any help will be great, I have seen people already asking and followed what people suggested to fixed but it did not work.
In the  config/application.rb

```
config.assets.version = '1.0'

     config.before_configuration do
        env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
        YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
        ENV[key.to_s] = value
     end if File.exists?(env_file)
    end
```

Comment: Are you sure `elasticbeanstalk-us-west-1-299430007588.s3.amazonaws.com8` is the correct bucket name?  It should not be a hostname, it should be just the bucket name as configured in S3.

Comment: It is the right bucket name, actually it's the way I set my environment variables because when I put the variables directly in production and development it saves in amazon s3m. However when I saved my variables in environment.yml is not connecting.

Comment: Which gem are you using that loads env vars from environment.yml?

Comment: I am not using any gem I followed this person's advice http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html , I am creating in locally.

Comment: Please update your question to show all the code you added to load the environment.yml then.

Comment: Is your file named local_env.yml or environment.yml?  Your code is looking for local_env.yml...

Comment: yes I changes to local_env.yml